# Django code to get IDs from queryset, shuffle IDs, and query database in shuffled order

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am trying to do the following in Django:

1. Do a database query to return the IDs of all records that satisfy the query.
2. Shuffle the list of IDs from the query into a random order.
3. Create a new queryset that gets records from the database in the shuffled order.

So if my initial database query looks like this:

```
queryset = Item.objects.filter(my_field = a_value)
```

How can I get at a list of IDs from the query so that I can shuffle with:

```
random.shuffle(list_of_ids_matching_query)
```

I.e. I want to create the `list_of_ids_matching_query` from the queryset, but I can't work out how to do that.

I then plan to do a query along the lines of:

```
queryset = Item.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_ids_matching_query)
```

But I need the query to return records in the same order as the IDs in the shuffled list. Will it do that? Or do I have to extract the records from the database one at a time.

What I am trying to do, and there may well be a better way to do this, is to get a random set of results in random order from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
list_of_ids_matching_query = list(Item.objects.filter(my_field = a_value).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

For getting records in the same order as the IDs in the shuffled list,

```
ordering = 'FIELD(`id`, %s)' % ','.join(str(id) for id in shuffiled_list)
Item.objects.filter(pk__in=shuffiled_list).extra(select={'ordering': ordering }, order_by=('ordering', ))
```

Comment: That creates the list of IDs perfectly thanks. Unfortunately the final stage of my quest for random results is returning the results in ID order rather than the random order of IDs in the shuffled list. Do you know if it is possible to force the query to return in the order of the shuffled list?

Comment: Brilliant! Works a charm.